# What unity tools should I use to draw 2d sprites on the screen?

Tags: unity-game-engine, 2d, game-engine

I am writing that in the likeness of a visual novel in unity. But not much oriented in its tools and assets. The idea is that I only need to draw certain sprats within the screen: characters, background, text, effects.

But only within the boundaries of the screen and it is desirable to control the position of these sprites should be in relative coordinates at the screen itself.

**But what is better to use for this?**

I assume that canvas suggests something similar (a UI display which should not go beyond the boundaries), but even if how exactly to draw? put panel on top of each other with alpha channel for each "layer": background, character, text?

**But how then to move sprites?**

Answer (score 1):

You could use the ganvas ui of Unity to put your backgrounds, Text and decision Buttons on the screen.
Then you should create a Dialogue Parser Script wich takes a text file, which will hold the actual text of what is happening and then present that text to the player. 
The file should contain information of the character, what each character should say, and what choices to give the player. 
Then you need a script that will actually show the game dialogue.
But I think there are plenty usefull tutorials on youtube and so on to create a simple 2D visual novel game.

If you never did a 2D Game in Unity before you could take a look at the 2D Game Tutorials:
https://learn.unity.com/project/creator-kit-rpg?language=en
This tutorial teaches you this 2d game creation fundamentals and only take one hour.

If you want to create a visual novel game without programming you could use this free Visual Novel Toolkit from the Unity Asset store:
https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/templates/visual-novel-toolkit-free-9416